# Area moments of parts of a rectangle divided by a line

Tags: geometry, linear-programming, area, intersection-theory, rectangles

I want to calculate the areas (and possibly their first and second moments) of a rectangle split into two parts by a line. It would be very helpful for me if there're closed form expressions for this for the general case.

Here's a schematic of what I have - I know the equation of the line in terms of it's normal and offset and I know that the rectangle is centered at the origin. In the figure below, I want to find the areas (and moments) of the red and blue regions respectively.

[image]

Maybe the solution is something very simple that I'm missing, but I'll be thankful for any help possible for this. I know that this is an oft-encountered scenario in linear programming.

Comment: Find the intersection with lines that form the rectangle. Knowing vertices of the rectangle, check which two sides of the rectangle the line intersects - two adjacent sides or two opposite sides. Then form equations for areas accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering if there's a simpler/more elegant way out there for this